# python BeautifulSoup - can't set attribute, trying to replace a tags value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

Im trying to check if the span tag has the string '~', if it does I want to replace it with '0'.

I've hundreds of span tags, I want to change the span.text value, as i want to copy the IF Statement to many places throughout my code, it wont work hard coding the var001 into the if statement.

How can i do this?

my code

```
span = soup.find("span", id="id001")
if span.text in  ['~']:
    span.text = 0
var001 = span.text
```

but this gives the error

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains to identify the relevant tags and leverage `string.replace_with` for the change in the `.text`. The ~ needs escaping to differentiate it from the general sibling combinator

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<span>some text ~ </span>
<span>some text</span>
<span>some ~ text</span>
<span>some text</span>
<span>~ some text</span>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for t in soup.select('span:contains(\~)'):
    t.string.replace_with('0')
print(soup)
```